# DbContext - Best Practice for Saving Child Collections when Working with Disconnected Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, n-tier-architecture

I'm attempting to separate my DbContext from a winforms application that I'm currently using to better support a multi-user environment as well as an upcoming website.  After doing a bit of research I've going with implementing a data access layer (DAL) for the winforms app/website to connect to and having the end-users work with disconnected entities.  My question is regarding the best way I would go about saving updates to my entities when one of the entities in a child collection has been updated.

For instance, if I have the following structure (simplified)

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }  // Non-virtual as we aren't lazy-loading
}

public class Employee
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
}

public class Claim
{
    public DateTime ClaimDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection Documentation { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public byte[] DocumentImage { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the winforms application, I have multiple Binding Source's set-up to display the employee's information

For Example:

```
employeeBinding.DataSource = typeof(Employee);   // Eventually set to an IEnumerable<Employee>
claimBinding.DataSource = employeeBinding;
claimBinding.DataMember = "Claims";
documentationBinding.DataSource = claimBinding;
documentationBinding.DataMember = "Documentation";
```

However, by setting things up like this I'm unable to make calls on the "CurrentChanged" event of each binding source to save each entity since it has changed (unless I have references stored to the previous entity inside the form).  So what I have thought to do was something similar to below in the DAL and iterate through each of the child collections.

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee employee) 
{
   using (myContext context = new myContext())
   {
     context.Employees.Attach(employee);
     context.Entry<Employee>(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;

     foreach(var claim in employee.Claims) 
     {
       context.Entry<Claim>(claim).State = EntityState.Modified;
       foreach(var doc in claim.Documentation)
       {
         context.Entry<Document>(doc).State = EntityState.Modified;
       }
     }
     context.SaveChanges(); 
   }
}
```

However, I feel that this route can get ugly quick with some more complex entities and relationships.  Could someone help point me to the best route to handle this or should I have references to the current entities in the code so when the "CurrentChanged" event fires I can just update each individual entity?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Entity Framework you have the ChangeTracker, even if you are using this "Disconected entities" you can have the ChangeTracker tracking the entities, to have this you just need to attach them to the context and before you call the SaveChanges you call .DetectCHanges() You dont really need to have this specific code, you can use generics for this:

```
public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) 
{
   using (myContext context = new myContext())
   {
     context.Set<TEntity>.Attach(entity);
     context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
     context.SaveChanges(); 
   }
}
```

the call to the method would be:

```
Update<Employee>(employees);
```

Also i think is better for you to use a BindingSouce as the DataSource, and set the DataSource of the BindingSource as a List instead of typeof(Employee)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't believe DetectChanges will be able to determine that there have been changes made to a disconnected entity. When the entity is attached, it will have an EntityState of "Unchanged" so wouldn't the DbContext do nothing with it until you mark it's state as "Modified".  Also, as indicated in the following URL, "DetectChanges" is called for a number of methods (including "Attach") anyways and the explicit call would not be needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx

As for the BindingSource, I was illustrating that that BindingSource will be set to typeof(Employee) as if I was setting up my code in the constructor before the load events where I would actually get my data and set it's datasource to an IEnumerable from the DAL call.  If I didn't do this, I would run into issues when attempting to bind to the "DataMember" properties as the other BindingSources wouldn't be able to find the properties indicated.

I don't believe that the code you provided as a sample fixes the issue I'm running into regarding child collections being updated.  When testing with LinqPad they'll be updated if the parent entity has changed as well, but not if there have been zero changes to the parent.  That's why I was iterating through all child collections and marking them as "Modified".